# how to make createMaterialTopTabNavigator tabBar backgroundcolor to Linear-gradient

Tags: react-native

I want to use backgroundcolor as linear gradient but while i am using react-native-linear-gradient it showing nothing as a white background

I want to change that blue color of tabbar to linear-gradient color .

Like this:

```js
<LinearGradient colors={['#ef7f1a','#fbb040']} start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          // end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}/>

const AppNavigationContainer = createAppContainer(

    createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
        All: {
            screen: AllData
        },
        Solar: {
            screen: Solar
        },
        Interior:{
            screen: InteriorData
        }
    },{
      tabBarOptions:{
        style:{
          // backgroundColor:<LinearGradient colors={['#ef7f1a','#fbb040']} start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          // end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}/>
        }
      }
  })
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tabBarComponent`

**Example**

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, MaterialTopTabBar } from "react-navigation"
...
tabBarComponent: props => return (
        <Fragment>
            <LinearGradient colors={['#ef7f1a','#fbb040']} start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
           end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}/>
            <MaterialTopTabBar/>
        </Fragment>

    )
```

Comment: its not working for me . can you show me your code if it is working?